# "Invalid root vertex id for dominator tree" Error using st_cuts in IGraph Package

Tags: r, igraph

Each time I try and use the ST_cuts command in the R IGraph package I get this error :

```
Error in st_cuts(g, source = 1, target = 5) : 
At st-cuts.c:415 : Invalid root vertex id for dominator tree, Invalid value
```

My network and code are shown below. Any recommendations on how to fix this issue.

I have tried changing the target node and recreating the network. The command works for the examples in the documentation.

```
library(igraph)
g<-graph_from_literal(1-+2,2+4,4+6,6+8,8+10,10+12,1-+12,2-+3,4-+5,6-+7,8-+9,10-+11,12-+13)
st_cuts(g, source=1, target=5)
```

[image: Picture of Network]

Comment: Try `st_cuts(g, source="1", target="5")`. I think you want the vertex names rather than their index

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Its always something so small.

Answer (score 0):

Try st_cuts(g, source="1", target="5"). I think you want the vertex names rather than their index – MrFlick